# clean install and drivers

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I just did a clean install of Windows Vista on my machine. I downloaded my drivers from website. Now the only thing I had to install was my network card and video driver and everything works fine as far as I'm concern.

However, do I really need the other stuff like BIOS and BIOS Utilities or any of the others? And if so, is there a certain order they need to be installed?

I only had one issue in my device driver list and that was the PCI Simple Communications Controller, not sure how I'd fine what driver I need to fix that?

[image]

Comment: I would check others or utilities. You can also open the properties and google the hardware ID it can sometimes help point to a device.

Answer (score 1):

Your BIOS is already installed. Do you need to download the BIOS on ASUS' website in order to update the version? Simply check your BIOS version during the POST screen and compare it to the BIOS version offered on ASUS' website.

Your BIOS doesn't change during a clean install. It's stored in a ROM chip, whereas all your drivers are located on your C: drive. Typically, C:\WINDOWS\system32\Drivers. Since you essentially wipe your C:\ drive clean during a clean install, all your drivers are eliminated, and thus, you need to reinstall them.

Regarding the PCI Simple Communications Controller, [this website](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/77E06491A6EF696E8625726000070545) states,

> PCI stands for Peripheral Component Interconnect and is an industry standard bus for attaching peripheral devices to a computer. The PCI Simple Communications Controller is a **generic label given by Windows to PCI boards installed in a PC when the drivers for the device are not installed**.

So, the question is, do you have something installed in one of the PCI slots on your motherboard? If so, you need to install its driver.

Please use the hyperlinked website to further investigate your problem, as it offers more solutions that may benefit you.